# Insert tags into database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I have a problem,I can't insert tags into database.I have 3 tables : 
Articles

```
id title content date
```

Tags

```
id name
```

Tags_in_news

```
id news_id tag_id
```

My html:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() .'administration/addArticle'; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

p><b>Title:</b></p>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" style="width:605px">
<p><b>Tags:</b></p>
  <input type="text" name="dropdiv" id="dropdiv" style="width:605"  /><br />
<p><b>Content:</b></p>
        <textarea name="content" id="content" style="width:605px; height: 300px;" rows="200"></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Method:

```
public function addArticle()
    {
    if ($this->input->post('title', TRUE) and($this->input->post('dropdiv',TRUE)) and strlen($this->input->post('title', TRUE))>3 ) 
    {
        $title     =     addslashes($this->input->post('title'));
        $content   =     addslashes($this->input->post('content'));
        $tags      =     $this->input->post('dropdiv');
        $date      =     date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $theid     =     $this->db->insert_id();


        $this->db->query("
                INSERT INTO articles (
                        title, 
                        content,
                        date) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                array(
                    $title, 
                    $content, 
                    $date)
            );

        foreach ($tags as $t) 
        {          
            $tag_SQL = $t;
            $this->db->query("insert into tags_in_news (news_id, tag_id) values ('{$theid}','{$tag_SQL}')");
        }
         redirect('administration/add_article', 'redirect');
    }
}
```

In the articles no problem data is storing, but in the table tags_in_news don't storing and I can't understand where is the problem...Help please

Comment: can you `print_r($tags)` and see what you get ?

Comment: I get nothing :) one more thing my dropdiv contains more words for example(first last third)

Comment: so are they separated by some delimiter like space comma etc ?

Comment: there is without separator like this (first last third)

Comment: so thats space ! you need to do as `$tags_arr = explode(' ',$tags)`; and then use `foreach($tags_arr as $t)`.

Comment: have to connect the tables with foreign key?I connect  but I get an error

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myblog`.`tags_in_news`, CONSTRAINT `tags_in_news_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`news_id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

insert into tags_in_news (news_id, tag_id) values ('0','yupi')

Comment: move this line `$theid = $this->db->insert_id();` below the first query.

Comment: Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myblog`.`tags_in_news`, CONSTRAINT `tags_in_news_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

insert into tags_in_news (news_id, tag_id) values ('31','yupi')

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\blogCI\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: Yes the `tag_id` is is foreign key and referring `tags` table. I am not aware of your DB design but looks like the tags needs to be added first on tag table and then get the id from tag table and add that id in the  `tags_in_news`

Comment: Yes tag exists into database